# Place of ng-app in html tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. My lecturer said ng-app can use in html, body, div tags etc. My question is, if ng-app can use in html tag and body tag, is there a any use if i use it in html tag rather than body tag? 
What I mean is, the head tag is middle of body and html. Is there any effect cause in head tags when I use it html tag or not. hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that you would place the ng-app inside the html tag over the body tag is because you want to manipulate something inside of the head and body using angularjs. Here is an example:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title ng-bind="'Title - ' + title"></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
...
```

Notice in the title I have a ng-bind, this way i can use the variable name `title` to change the title of the web page the user is on. The title will always be Title - `what ever link their on` In the app.js I make the `title` var a global variable. This is just one reason to put ng-app in the html tag instead of body.

Answer (score 5):

No. `ng-app` has no effect on `<head>` unless you intend to. It should be added to the element which is the `scope` of your app, the root element `html`.

Most of the time it is better to use it on `body` tag unless you want to change something in `head` e.g. `title`. For dynamic value of `title`, `ng-app` should be added to the `<html>`.

Comment: Great handy hint, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

yes there are some benefits if you put `ng-app` in the `<html>` tag,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

if u put it in html then you can control all the things between html tag, that mean all html can be manipulate using angularjs, for **EX** you can change the title.

But if you put it in `<body>` then you loose the control of the `<title>` or something inside the `<head>` tags and you can control the inside the `<body>` tag only.

here is the DOC for [NG-APP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the <body> or <html> tags.